# Why faces created with Bsurfaces are not visible?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

[image]

The first Greasse pencil stroke works fine but after I add second stroke I cant see the faces.Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

### Check normals orientation

It is possible that some faces has negative normals facing to the cam. You should be able to recognize them by their darker blueish color once the "**Backface Culling**" option is disabled in the 3D view properties panel.

[image]

Bsurface take in account the **sequence** in which you draw each strokes to understand where the normals are pointing, according to the created face index.

[image]

With backface culling enabled, Blender will not show the faces who are pointing not toward the camera. Edges remain though, leading to your situation.

I suggest you to select Backfaces and run the **Flip normals** commmand.